# Apply Search to Multiple Columns

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using DataTables version 1.10.16 and I currently have a datatable initialized as such:

```
// Setup the emails datatable
var auto_responders = $('#auto_responders').DataTable({
  ajax: {
    url: "assets/php/get_auto_responders.php",
    dataSrc: ''
  },
  columns: [
    { data: 'user_first_name', title: 'User Name', createdCell:
  function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
  $(td).text(cellData + ' ' + rowData['user_last_name']);
}
},
    { data: 'user_last_name', visible: false},
    { data: 'customer_first_name', title: 'Customer Name', createdCell:
  function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
  $(td).text(cellData + ' ' + rowData['customer_last_name']);
}
},
    { data: 'customer_last_name', visible: false},
    { data: 'email', title: 'Email', createdCell:
  function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
  $(td).html('<a href="mailto:' + cellData + '">' + cellData + '</a>');
}
},
    { data: 'customer_id', searchable: false, visible: false },
    { data: 'date_entered', title: 'Date Entered' },
    { data: 'title', title: 'Auto-Responder' },
    { data: 'queued_ids', title: 'Upcoming Responders', searchable: false, createdCell:
      function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
        if (!cellData) {
    $(td).html('<span class="text-danger text-center d-block">No Automatic Responders Queued</span>');
  } else {
    $(td).html('<button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-outline-success queued_auto_responders" data-queued-ids="' + cellData + '" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_queued_responders">View Queued Automatic Responders</button>');
  }
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

As you can tell, I'm combining the first two (user's first and last name) and then next two columns (customer's first and last name) when they're displayed, but I'm setting the respective last name columns' visibility to false.

To create a dropdown filter for the person on the webpage to quickly view all rows for a particular user I have the following code:

```
auto_responders.columns([0, 1]).search(filter).draw();
```

Where the value `filter` equals that of the full name of a user. My issue is that I thought by specifying the first two columns that it'd try to match the name in the filter to the first and last name of the user, but when I try to use that code, no rows are returned. How can I get it to where it returns the row based on where the first and second column both contain at least a portion of the filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do custom search filtering with the search api in datatables

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search
```

Example here [Custom Filtering](https://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html)

Comment: Thank you, it took some debugging but ultimately I used `indexOf` on both the first and last name columns based on the filter.